# Display correct image with coffeescript fancybox-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, fancybox

I have some thumbnails, when you click them that image get displayed in the .big-img. I use fancybox-rails to then display that image in full-size. That works great, but my problem now is to get the selected thumbnail to be displayed with fancybox. Right now the path only leads to the first image, so no matter which thumbnail is displayed in big-img, only the first image is displayed with fancybox.

html.erb

```
<%=link_to (@product.images.first.url), :class => 'fancyframe', :rel => 'group' do %>
   <div class="big-img"> <%= image_tag(@product.images.first.url) %></div>
<% end %>

<% if @product.images.count > 1 %>
  <% @product.images.each do |image| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag((image.url), :class => 'thumb')%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

js.coffee

```
jQuery ->  $(".thumb").click ->
  val = $(this).attr("src")
  $(".big-img").html "<img src=\"" + val + "\" />"
  return false;

jQuery ->
 $(".fancyframe").fancybox
  type: "iframe"
  width: 900 
  height: 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know either coffescript or rails but looking at your code my guess is that this script

```
<%=link_to (@product.images.first.url), :class => 'fancyframe', :rel => 'group' do %>
   <div class="big-img"> <%= image_tag(@product.images.first.url) %></div>
<% end %>
```

renders an html like this (at the end this is what it matters)

```
<a href="{image FIRST URL}" class="fancyframe" rel="group">
    <div class="big-img">
        <img src="{image FIRST URL}" />
    </div>
</a>
```

Then this script

```
jQuery ->  $(".thumb").click ->
  val = $(this).attr("src")
  $(".big-img").html "<img src=\"" + val + "\" />"
  return false;
```

...changes the thumbnail image (`<img />` tag) inside the container `<div class="big-img">` but the `href` of the parent link (`<a>` tag with `class="fancyframe"`) is still pointing to the first image URL.

You also have to change the `href` of the `.fancyframe` selector like

```
jQuery ->  $(".thumb").click ->
  val = $(this).attr("src")
  $(".big-img").html "<img src=\"" + val + "\" />"
  $(".fancyframe").attr("href", val); // write this in coffescript format
  return false;
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAm7A/)**